# Real Sequence Arithmetic and Geometric Progression Problems

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

At what rate of interest will a single investment triple its value in 5years?

Guys, please help me here, so far I have done this:

Using the formula;

a + (n-1)d

let the first term (a) = 1

Let the nth term = 5

find d?

substituting all the values into the formula I have

1 + (5-1)d
1 + 5d - d = 0
5d - d = 0-1
4d = -1
4d/4 = -1/4

d = -1/4

d = 0.25%

I don't have any idea what I am doing is right, but am I in line?

Comment: Is the interest compounded annually or continuously?

Comment: Really, bro, I have no idea, that is exactly the way the question came?

Comment: Well, as I said, this is exactly how the question came and that is the more reason  I am confused too because I taught the same.

Comment: Can you take the compounding interest as an instance work with that, I want to see how you go about solving it. I just need work though on how to tackle such a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple interest** In line with the usual notation for arithmetic progressions, we'll take the convention that time starts at the first term, not zeroth. The investment's value is $a+(n-1)d$ at time $n$, i.e. the investment starts at $n=1$< not at $n=0$. The value grows from $a$ at $n=1$ to $3a=a+5d$ when the investment ends at $n=6$. Rearranging $d=\frac25 a$ i.e. the annual interest rate is $40\%$.

**Compound interest** Similar logic gives $3a=ar^5$, with $a$ the initial investment value and $r$ the common ratio. Thus $r=3^{1/5}$. Then the interest rate per annum is $100(3^{1/5}-1)\%\approx 24.57\%$.

Comment: can u break it down a bit, I am quite confused?

Comment: @PreciousAdeyinka Sure. I hope my edit helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, @J.G I think you must have done justice to this, am so grateful for your help... I will read up on more A.P & G.P to grab a stronghold of this concept properly.

Comment: @PreciousAdeyinka Glad to help. It looks like your mistake was solving $1+4d=0$ instead of $1+5d=3$.

Comment: Ohh yeah, I guess my major problem was interpreting the problem in the first place.